# Finding the average population of countries in a specific region

Tags: python-3.x, csv, average

The function requires the input of a region where I need to be able to return the output of the average population of the country's in the region. All the country's and regions and any other data (population are given in the csv file)

```
import csv
import math

def main(file_name, region):
    min_population = math.inf
    max_population = -math.inf
    min_country = None
    max_country = None
    total_pop = 0
    num_countries = 0

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        countries = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file) if row['Regions'] == region and float(row['Net Change']) > 0]

    for row in countries:
        population = int(row['Population(2020)'])

        if population < min_population:
            min_population = population
            min_country = row['Name']

        if population > max_population:
            max_population = population
            max_country = row['Name']

    return min_country, max_country


    for row in countries:
        if row['Name'] == region:     #Calculates the average population for a specific region
            total_pop = total_pop + int(row['Population(2020)'])
            num_countries = num_countries + 1
        if num_countries > 0:
            average_pop = total_pop / num_countries
            return average_pop
        else:
            return None
```

with the code above I get an output of nothing in regards to the average population of the country's in the specific region.

Comment: `countries` is already those in the given region.

Comment: Yeah it is the countries in the given region. But that last for loop in my code isn't providing the average population for those countries.

Comment: you return from the function call before it ever gets a chance to. even then your if looks like it will filter everything out. Is `row["name"]` ever going to be the region?

Comment: Hi I would like to help you you with a code sample using pandas. However, could you please provide me with an example of the CSV file that you are using? It would be helpful if you can include at least three rows with random data and all the necessary columns required for this function.

Comment: Why do you expect your function to continue running after you `return min_country, max_country`?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If so, please accept one.

Answer (score 0):

`yield` aside, you can only ever really `return` from a function once so we need to get all the results needed to do that.

Additionally, the countries have already been filtered to those in the given region so like any kind of test to redo that is unneeded.

Finally, you might also take a look at the `statistics` module that does a bunch of this stuff.

```py
import csv
import math

def main(file_name, region):
    min_country = None
    max_country = None
    min_population = math.inf
    max_population = -math.inf
    total_population = 0
    total_countries = 0

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        countries = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file) if row['Regions'] == region and float(row['Net Change']) > 0]
    
    if not countries:
        return None, None, None

    for row in countries:
        population = int(row['Population(2020)'])
        total_countries += 1
        total_population += population

        if population < min_population:
            min_population = population
            min_country = row['Name']

        if population > max_population:
            max_population = population
            max_country = row['Name']

    return min_country, max_country, total_population / total_countries
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last `for` loop there is an incorrect `if` statement. It is checking if country name equals region. It should be

```py
for row in countries:
        if row['Regions'] == region:     #Calculates the average population for a specific region
```

But, when you read in the `countries` list you are already filtering for only `row['Regions']==region`. Therefore, the `if` statement I corrected is not needed in your last `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found some data at https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tanuprabhu/population-by-country-2020?resource=download that looked
almost identical to what you were describing.  I had to add a Region column, and I just went with foo, bar, and baz for mock regions:

```
Region,Country,Population (2020),Yearly Change,Net Change
foo,China,1440297825,0.39,5540090
bar,India,1382345085,0.99,13586631
foo,United States,331341050,0.59,1937734
...
foo,Niue,1628,0.68,11
bar,Tokelau,1360,1.27,17
baz,Holy See,801,0.25,2
```

I think it might actually be easier to do everything in one main loop of the rows from your DictReader.  You can easily filter rows out by using `continue` if they **don't** match your criteria:

```py
import csv


def get_stats(region: str, fname: str) -> tuple[str, str, int]:
    min_name = ""
    min_pop = 1e12  # good-enough upper bound on a nation's population
    max_name = ""
    max_pop = 0  # good-enough lower bound
    pop_sum = 0
    pop_ct = 0

    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        for row in reader:
            if row["Region"] != region:
                continue
            if float(row["Net Change"]) <= 0:
                continue

            pop = int(row["Population (2020)"])
            country = row["Country"]

            if pop > max_pop:
                max_name = country
                max_pop = pop

            if pop < min_pop:
                min_name = country
                min_pop = pop

            pop_sum += pop
            pop_ct += 1

    avg_pop = pop_sum / pop_ct

    # print(f"found {pop_ct} countries in region '{region}' with net-positive population change")
    # print(f"smallest is {min_name} w/population {min_pop}")
    # print(f"largest is {max_name} w/population {max_pop}")
    # print(f"average population of group is {avg_pop:.4g}")

    return min_name, max_name, int(round(avg_pop, 0))


print(get_stats("foo", "input.csv"))
print(get_stats("bar", "input.csv"))
print(get_stats("baz", "input.csv"))
```

That prints:

```py
('Niue', 'China', 45874000)
('Tokelau', 'India', 40135471)
('Holy See', 'Pakistan', 24044418)
```